# While creating my first Docker image from an online tutorial , I get this error

Tags: docker

I am new to Docker and following some tutorial on creating my first Docker Image and I get the error below:

```
Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder645461097/Dockerfile: is a directory
```

[image: screenshot]

Any idea about what I am doing wrong and how I can solve it ?

Comment: Update your question with your scripts/commandline - then we can help you.

Comment: Hi! Can you include your Dockerfile in the post?

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the directory with your Dockerfile and not in the directory with the folder with the name `Dockerfile`?
When you are executing the command `docker build .` the current directory should have Dockerfile where with your commands like `FROM ...` etc.

Comment: @ValeriiBoldakov am not sure of this because I created a file and named in Docker but I see its a folder with a file named untitled3 that has my content

Comment: Add more information about your folder structure, please.
Like what is a path for your Dockefile? And what is the path where you call the `docker build` command?

Comment: Check out the screenshot  I shared

Comment: @NullDocker20, check out my edited answer.

Comment: Can you show the folder structure and the included files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the next file structure for your project:

1. The top-level directory `environment`.
2. The folder `./environment/Dockerfile`.
3. And the file `./environment/Dockerfile/Dockerfile`.

Right now you are executing the command `docker build .` from the directory `environment`. It looks for the entity with the name `Dockerfile` but it's a folder. It needs a textfile Dockerfile with your configuration.

There are some options to fix it:

1. Change directory to `./Dockerfile` with the command `cd Dockerfile`. You will be executing your command from the `./environment/Dockerfile` directory.
2. Or specify the path to the Dockerfile with `-f` flag. Like in: `docker build -f Dockerfile/Dockerfile .` [More information about the `-f` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files).

Answer (score 1):

In your case `Dockerfile` is a folder. However, the `Dockerfile` must be a file with commands to create the Docker image. Maybe the following [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) will help you.